# Cookie в PHP. Не удаляются куки из всех подразделов домена

Tags: php, cookie

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь перезаписать cookie на всем домене во всех разделах, но перезаписываются только в  корневой директории сайта.

Скрипт:

```
setcookie("nsc_visID","",1,'/');
```

Comment: в смысле в корневой директории?

Comment: т.е. как вы так определили сколько coock в браузере с вашего сайта?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Корневая директория, например : www.examlpe,com/(корневая директория), то есть все файлы, которые не находятся в папках, например : www.examlpe,com/example.php  - в данных файлах, cookie удаляются

Comment: Cookie, определяю с помощью, расширений firefox.

Answer (score 2):

`setcookie("nsc_visID","",1,'.domain.com');`

"domain.com" замените, а вот точку спереди не трогайте.

**.domain.com** - это обращение ко всем поддоменам.

**P.S.** Таким же способом решается вопрос авторизации на всех поддоменах сайта.

Comment: Доброе утро, спасибо за ответ. Я работаю на под домене. Если я указываю:   setcookie("nsc_visID","",1,'.domain.com') со своим доменом, то куки у меня больше нигде не переписываются(удаляются). Самое странное, что функция setcookie возвращает true. Cookie устанавливаются сразу после <?php, данный файл нигде не подгружается, на него ссылаются, это logout.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно устанавливаете куки - 4 параметром должен быть Ваш домен

```
setcookie("nsc_visID","",1,'http://domain.ru');
```

[Документация по кукам в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: Говорите домен, а сами написали url

Comment: Доброе утро, спасибо за ответ. Такая же ситуация, если я пропускаю параметр '/',  потом указываю под домен или домен, у меня  перестают очистятся cookie везде, а если setcookie("nsc_visID","",1,'/'); , то очищаются, но только в корневой директории. Указывая принудительно раздел в котором необходимо очистить cookie setcookie("nsc_visID","",1,'/advertiser');, то все работает , но если я буду указывать для каждого раздела индивидуально, это будет не красиво) и точно не правильно.